# Changing DPI with adb

Tags: adb, htc

I have a HTC Evo 3D and i want to change the DPI. I am not rooted but I know that using adb and putting the command 
`adb shell wm density 200` 
I will be able to change my DPI. But i am getting this error
`system/bin/sh: wm: not found`

What can i do to avoid this error.
Thanks

Comment: Try `adb shell wm density 200` instead.

Comment: It was suppose to be adb shell in my question, sorry